# Potential signature malleability in Solidity CTF

Tags: solidity, signature, ecrecover, hack

I am doing a CTF so I don't want to give too much information away. I am pretty sure I can practice signature malleability or otherwise abuse the signer functions to be able to mint tokens given the two functions below:

```
 /// @dev Sets a new signer account. Only the current signer can call this function
function setSigner(address _newSigner) public {
    require(msg.sender != signer, "You are not the current signer");
    signer = _newSigner;
}

/// @dev Used in case we decide totalSupply must be increased
function mintTokensWithSignature(
    uint256 amount,
    bytes32 _r,
    bytes32 _s,
    uint8 _v
) public {
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(
        abi.encode(address(this), amount, msg.sender)
    );
    bytes32 hashToCheck = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix, messageHash));
    require(
        signer == ecrecover(hashToCheck, _v, _r, _s),
        "Wrong signature"
    );
    _mint(msg.sender, amount);
}
```

I already know that I can abuse the setSigner() function and set whatever signer I want... I am not quite sure how I can leverage this to be able to mint tokens. Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

once you have used `setSigner` to set `signer` to an address/account you control, you can use that account to call `mintTokenWithSignature` and you'll not be stopped by this check in the `mintTokenWithSignature` function

```
require(
    signer == ecrecover(hashToCheck, _v, _r, _s),
    "Wrong signature"
);
```

Comment: but I AM stopped by this. I am still pretty new to solidity and I am not sure where to obtain the _v, _r, _s  values. Setting the signer doesn't give me that information.

Am I able to find it somewhere in memory? Do I have to use the web3.eth.sign function?